# AND Statements in JOIN vs WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to understand why the following happens (example code below).

```
-- Returns 1,000
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_ONE t1
WHERE t1.FIELD_ONE = 'Hello';

-- Returns 1,000
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_ONE t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_TWO t2 ON t2.TABLE_ONE_ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.FIELD_ONE = 'Hello'
AND t2.FIELD_TWO = 'Goodbye';

-- Returns 83,500
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_ONE t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_TWO t2 ON (t2.TABLE_ONE_ID = t1.ID AND t2.FIELD_TWO = 'Goodbye')
WHERE t1.FIELD_ONE = 'Hello';
```

I understand that left outer joins will always include the left value even if a right value is not found, etc. However, I thought that adding additional conditions to `JOIN` clauses would restrict what is done in the `JOIN`.

So for example if I had entry A from TABLE_ONE, then it would look for a TABLE_TWO value that met the 2 conditions. If one wasn't found, it would just be blank. But that entry A would only appear once in the result set. So I am confused why I am getting so many more results then what is actually in the original TABLE_ONE query.

**UPDATE**

To explain more what I am trying to understand. The resulting query (not using the `COUNT`) results in something like this.

```
Table_One_Name    Table_Two_Value
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Entry A           Goodbye
Entry A           
Entry A
Entry A
Entry B           Goodbye
Entry B
```

I don't understand why the `JOIN` is adding rows when the 2 conditions are not met.

Comment: instead of a `select count(*)`, do `select *` and compare the actual returned rows from both queries. you'll quickly see the differences between the results in your #2 and #3 queries.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed they are doing multiple joins for the same TABLE_ONE entry. I just want to know why.

Comment: PLease read:http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: @HLGEM That article really helped. Thanks! If you put it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Mark @FrankPl as correct. he essentially says teh same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where clause
```

filters the records, first case has an additional condition  `AND t2.FIELD_TWO = 'Goodbye' which filters more records(about 73,500 records)`

```
-- Returns 1,000
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_ONE t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_TWO t2 ON t2.TABLE_ONE_ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.FIELD_ONE = 'Hello'
AND t2.FIELD_TWO = 'Goodbye';
```

Left outer join brings all the records even it does not have a match
In your second case `AND t2.FIELD_TWO = 'Goodbye` this is part of the left outer join
so it brings matching and non matching records

Comment: So does this mean that the `AND` is essentially ignored in the `JOIN`? I don't get why it chooses to just ignore the second condition.

Comment: it does not ignore that is how LEFT outer join works,left outer join brings matching and non matching records from left hand side table(TABLE_ONE t1) and only the matching records from  the right side table ( TABLE_TWO t2)

Comment: I did notice that when I did a `SELECT UNIQUE t2.FIELD_TWO` I got both Goodbye and blank.

Comment: yes where ever you see 'GoodBye' that is matching record and blank/null are non-matching records

Comment: I meant by ignore in the second condition. I am trying to understand why for a TABLE_ONE entry A there are multiple resulting rows. It is joining all the "Goodbye" rows and all the non-"Goodbye" rows. So entry A appears in multiple rows in the query result.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx read this and in the same query just do inner join instead of left outer you will see the difference

Comment: I get the inner vs outer join thing. It's just this situation. Like, always include the `TABLE_ONE` entry, even if a match isn't found in `TABLE_TWO`. But then it also seems to say - and join `TABLE_TWO` rows even if they don't meet the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: So it includes `TABLE_TWO` entries in the `JOIN` even if they aren't "Goodbye" entries.

Comment: As long as t2.FIELD_TWO = 'Goodbye' is part of the join that is the way it works

Comment: "that is the way it works" meaning it does include non-matching rows?

Comment: yeeeeeeep it does include non-matching rows.

Comment: But the weird thing is that it doesn't include all of the non-matching rows apparently.

Comment: @Rachel G. Do you have an example of a row that is missing in your opinion?

Comment: @FrankPl No. It was more that I'd either expect the count of `TABLE_ONE` or the multiplication of the counts of `TABLE_ONE` and `TABLE_TWO`. I just don't get how it's deciding whether to join.

Comment: @Rachel G As I stated in my answer above: First the (inner or outer) join is executed, and then the WHERE condition applied on the result of that step. If the JOIN is OUTER, then records not fulfilling the JOIN condition (and this does not consist only of the match of the foreign key to the primary key, but ALL conditions in the ON clause!) will be added from the outer side, and all columns of the other side will be NULL. In the second step, when teh WHERE is evaluated, NULL does not fulfill the condition to be 'GOODBYE'.

Comment: Ah. I figured out the issue. My bad. There is actually a 4 level join and I was not thinking about the implication of the other joins.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE condition is applied **after** the JOIN condition, and hence removes all the records containing NULL in `t2.FIELD_TWO`, thus effectively denying the purpose of the "OUTER" part of the JOIN.